# Random sample with gap sizes

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, random

Lets say I have 101 instances of `data` with multiple attributes. In particular case, one attribute has 7 unique values. I want to get `7<=n<=101` element positions from `data`, in a way that it contains at least 1 of each unique attribute case.

First I get the example data and gather it by particular attribute:

```
data = Import["https://raw.github.com/BioGeek/aima/master/aima-data-read-only/zoo.csv"];
g = GatherBy[data, #[[18]] &];
```

List `g` of lists with element sizes `h`

```
h = Length[#] & /@ g (*{41,13,20,10,8,4,5}*)
```

Following works in the best case scenario

```
n = RandomInteger[{Length[g], Length[data]}]
l = RandomSample[RandomSample[#] & /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {Length[g]}], 1][[1]]
s = Table[RandomSample[g[[i]], l[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[g]}]
p = Sort[Position[data, #][[1]][[1]] & /@ #] & /@ s
```

Example result:

```
{{30,33},{8,62},{57,72,96,101},{14,73,78,82,86},{25,40,43,89},{26,27,53,90},{77,81,91,92}}
```

I can bruteforce, but I do not like the idea.

```
While[MemberQ[Table[h[[i]] >= l[[i]], {i, 1, Length[h]}], False], 
 l = RandomSample[RandomSample[#] & /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {Length[g]}], 1][[1]]]
```

How do I find random sample `l` so it is less then gap sizes `h`?

**edit:**

> If n = 7

[image]

> If n = 21

[image]

Problem is that `h = {41,13,20,10,8,4,5}` and even if `n = 11` then `l = {1,1,1,1,1,5,1}` that is invalid as there are not enough elements in that sublist.

**edit 2**

```
f[data_List, n_Integer] := Module[{data1 = data, h, k},
  k = RandomSample[DeleteCases[data1, Alternatives @@
      (h = RandomChoice /@ GatherBy[data1, #[[18]] &])], n - 7];
  h~Union~k]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding this.  Could you try again to explain, please?

Comment: If 'n = 7', i want to take sample positions of 7 unique elements from the data. If n is larger, i want to take more elements. Selection must have 1 element of each attribute 18 category {mammal, fish, bird, ...}(7 in total).

Comment: I can't understand your sentence _"How do I find random sample l so it is less then gap sizes h?"_

Comment: Why not base the number of elements chosen in a given sublist on the length of that sublist? That way you will never request more than you have. [Note: You really have not stated clearly what is your "randomness" requirement. Thus it is difficult to give a specific answer.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first chooses one element from each subset, and then takes the rest from the complement using the whole set (discarding those previously taken). It doesn't assume a fixed number of classes, and calculates it from the length of the first choice.

```
f[data_List, n_Integer] := 
   #~Union~RandomSample[DeleteCases[data, Alternatives @@ #], n - Length@#] &@
                                              (RandomChoice /@ GatherBy[data, #[[18]] &])
```